# Eclipse keeps jumping to the start of the document

Tags: javascript, eclipse, editor

I have been using Eclipse for some weeks now and I start getting used to it.

However, one thing really annoys me:
When editing JavaScript (I didn't try any other language yet), the editor window keeps jumping to the start of the document I am editing.

This mostly happens when the code currently contains syntax errors and mostly while / after deleting lines.
Especially constructs like `{ =` and sometimes unterminated strings / comments seem to cause this problem.

When it happens, only the view scrolls to the top of the document - the cursor stays where it was before the "jump" occurred.

Anyone having an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Why the vote to close as Off-Topic? According to http://stackoverflow.com/faq stackoverflow is for questions related to "software tools commonly used by programmers", too.

Comment: Amazingly this bug still exists in 2016. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Boundless: "Solution" for me was to switch to another editor (Notepad++, VS Code, Visual Studio). Haven't really been using Eclipse to edit JavaScript for a while.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem described above is related to this bug:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=318095

The work around is to disable the "Link with Editor" option from the Project Explorer. Which is to say make sure the icon with two arrows facing in opposite directions at the top of the file tree is not enabled. Disabling this option resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with the implementation of the JavaScript editor. Most probably the jump occurs when the JavaScript-Parser is not able to parse your document and throws an exception. You might consider to report a bug to the eclipse project (maybe there is already such a report?).

As a workaround you might consider to adapt your way of typing the code a bit. Try to write the code in a way that does not confuse the parser (for example it might help to immediately close a newly created comment and THEN write the content instead of open the comment, write the content and finally close the commend). Same for strings, blocks ...

Comment: The problem with reporting a bug: I can not actually reproduce it - it just happens every couple of minutes. Otherwise, I would rather switch to Notepad++ before adapting my way of coding to an IDE ;-)

Comment: I can imagine that it is hard to reproduce. If you don't mind that much just don't report it and switch to Notepad++. The problem boils down to question if the features the IDE provides to you outnumber the problems you get from it.If I am faster with an IDE than with an text editor, I adapt my programming style to it to get most out of it. If not, I use a text editor (and adapt my coding style to that).

Comment: I have the same problem too. I'll start typing, then it jumps to the top of the page. Using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Indigo Service Release 2 Build id: 20120216-1857

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.  I had this line of code in my file and I could consistently reproduce the issue:

```
$.preload(preloadImages
                , {
                 base:assetsUrl+'b/images/',
                 ext:'.png'
                });
```

I changed it to the following and I no longer have the problem.

```
$.preload(preloadImages, {
                     base:assetsUrl+'b/images/',
                 ext:'.png'
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this Phenomenon, when i'm editing in a Java-Class while still residing in a Debug-Process. The Debugger recognises the Change and reevaluates the Code and jumps back in order to be able to reexecute only the changed Code.

Answer (score 0):

Hii i got solution goto

> `Window`->`Preferences`->search **`autosave`**

and disble it and hit apply and close button.
this worked for me !